# Jquery countdown plugin, how to synchronize to server time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-countdown

I want to have countdown until 22:00 (10:00 PM) on my server.

I couldn't understand from the [documentary](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) what should be the exact way to do so,
I've managed to define the time to be pulled from the server (though in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee7cL2dc/2/) it doesn't work, maybe it refuses to grab that servertime.php),

and define 22 as the hour value, but it doesn't work, it just adds +22 hours to the current time.

1. How should this be done?
2. Do I really need all this code, and that external php (that comes with 2 additional .js resoruces) just to achieve what I want?

HTML:

```
<span id="vvv"></span>
```

JS:

```
$('#vvv').countdown({ 
    until:new Date(2014, 11 - 1, 9, 22, 0, 0), serverSync: serverTime, layout: '{hn} {hl}, {mn} {ml}, {sn} {sl}'}

                   ); 

function serverTime() { 
    var time = null; 
    $.ajax({url: 'http://keith-wood.name/servertime.php', 
        async: false, dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }}); 
    return time; 
}
```